# How can I include graphics with transparency in LaTeX?

Tags: export

The EPS format does not support transparency.  How can I then include Mathematica graphics that have transparency in LaTeX documents?

Comment: You should like to the mentioned question. At the moment, your question seems very similar, so it may count as a duplicate.

Comment: I edited the question and answer to read what I think you actually meant. Please review the edit.  You can accept your own answer.

Comment: See my comment to your answer. It appears that the question is talking about plain `latex`, and not `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Rasterize` before exporting to a `.eps` file.

```
fig = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Sphere[]}]
```

[image]

Now `Export` like

```
Export["fig2.eps", Rasterize[fig]]
```

which will preserve the opacity in `.eps`. For better resolution you can use `RasterSize`.

For comparison

```
Export["fig1.eps", fig]
```

Then I use them in a tex file and this is how they look in pdf

[image]

Left is without `Rasterize` (fig1.eps) and right with `Rasterize` (fig2.eps).

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX also supports PDF, not only EPS.  Export the graphics in PDF format.

In LaTeX, add `\usepackage{graphicx}` to the preamble, and include the PDF file using

```
\includegraphics{file.pdf}
```

Compile the document using `pdflatex`.  Transparency is preserved.

Comment: This does not seem to be an answer...

Comment: Why ? I have encounter the problem many time. I have observed that when you save a picture in eps from mathematica the background may be transparent. But if I surimpose say a Triangle with a light opacity, the transparency is not preserved. With my solution it is the case

Comment: Okay - you should then perhaps add this answer to the thread you mention. The question together with this answer was not clear to me from the start. This answer is more about a TeX implementation...

Comment: I have tried to add it but as I havbe written in the Ps of the question it was forbiden

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The question was "How do I flatten transparency on a graphics, for conversion to eps or similar?"  I think most of us are already aware that (1) PDF supports transparency and (2) PDF can easily be included in LaTeX (neither of which are facts related to Mathematica)  But in many cases one is *required* to use EPS and PDF absolutely isn't an option.  **Exporting to PDF doesn't flatten transparency.  It simply preserves transparency in a format that supports it.**  There are genuine use cases for actually flattening transparency.

Comment: I'm saying this because recently the same problem caused me *a lot* of headache. Some journals only accept EPS, but not PDF.

Comment: I am not upset by your answer, but Stack exchange is not frequented only by people who master computing

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki You could rephrase your question so it asks something that this *is* an answer for.  I'm not saying it's not useful.  Such as: How to include Mathematica-generated vector figures in LaTeX documents, or similar.

Comment: Actually, this isn't quite correct. `PDF` can be used by `pdflatex` and newer engines such as `lualatex`, but not the original plain `latex`. Your distribution may switch to `pdflatex` automatically, but strictly it's then no longer plain `latex`.