# There are unwanted edges when export Polygon plot

Tags: plotting, polygons

Simple codes:

```
pol = Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}];
aa = Graphics[{Red, Opacity[0.2], EdgeForm[], pol}]
Export["cc.pdf", aa]
```

I just want to remove the edges when exporting it in pdf format.

[image]

Comment: Version 13.0 Your code seems to work.

Comment: I use 13.0 on win10, and it has edges when exporting to a pdf file.

Comment: I can confirm the behaviour in ``12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 24, 2021)``. As suggested [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136716/75628), use ``Graphics[{Red, Opacity[0.2], EdgeForm[AbsoluteThickness[-1]], pol}]``.