# When I save a RegionPlot result that I have used Opacity for its color, it contains redundant grid lines; how to get rid of them?

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

I am using `RegionPlot` and I want to use `Opacity` for the color transparency

```
RegionPlot[x - 3 Sin[y] < 0, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.3]], BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

But when I save the result, it contains some random grid lines inside it; how can I get rid of them? I need a clear plot.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDF export of polygons: How to get rid of polygon boundary lines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136523/pdf-export-of-polygons-how-to-get-rid-of-polygon-boundary-lines) or [Problem with exporting RegionPlot as PDF](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257039/problem-with-exporting-regionplot-as-pdf)

Comment: Seems that the problem is the same, but, I do not understand how I can apply their solution to my case. Can someone please help? @Domen